# Checking the existence of a permission object in Django unit test

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-testing, django-permissions

Suppose that I want to write a test to make sure that a permission does not exist. I want the following test to pass (instead it gives an error):

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

class TestPermission(TestCase):
  def test_existence_of_permission(self):
    self.assertIsNone(Permission.objects.get(codename='a_non_existant_permission'))
```

This gives me the following error:

```
django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: Permission matching query does not exist.
```

How can I test the non-existence of this permission?

Answer (score 4):

I figured this out:

I should have treatead `Permission` as a regular Django model.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

class TestPermission(TestCase):
  def test_existence_of_permission(self):
    self.assertFalse(Permission.objects.filter(
      codename='a_non_existant_permission').exists())
```